# Best string-comparison algorithm for regex

Tags: regex, string-comparison, edit-distance

Given a regex, I want to compare it with a list of other regex, and output a similarity score.

There are several edit distance algorithms out there (e.g. levenshtein distance), but they fail to compare regex's, e.g.:

```
R1:       [a-z0-9]+
R2:       [0-9]{1}[a-z0-9]+
Distance: 9
```

In the example above, both regex's are quite similar, however they have a quite high edit distance. I suppose an approach using character n-grams would be more suitable for such cases.

What algorithm/approach would you consider for this problem?

Comment: What is your goal?  Is it to determine the quality of a regex, i.e., to predict performance?

Comment: This seems like a hard problem, possibly equivalent to the halting problem. It's like comparing what two programs do.

Comment: It's possible to have two regexps that look pretty different, but are actually equivalent. E.g. `\d` versus `[0-9]`.

Comment: @varontron the ultimate goal would be to have an interpreter able to compare semantics, but I would be happy with some sort of sub-string comparison. The use case is to determine if a script (containing a regex) is trying to validate certain html input fields.

Comment: I don't know why there is a close vote. This is a valid question, despite not being straightforward and eventually not fully solvable

Comment: Does the score imply the suitability of a regex to process one or more known "classes" of strings?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're unlikely to improve upon the regular expression parsing algorithm present in an engine itself, because you're ultimately going to be making inferences about combinations of rules.

There are a number of open source regular expression engines, many listed on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular-expression_engines), possibly including the one you're using.

Without having looked at the internals myself (not an insignificant caveat,) my recommendation is to see if it's possible to modify a regex engine (or leverage some pre-existing debugging or testing code) to output pertinent rules-processing metadata, sub-scores, if you will, from which you can then calculate an aggregate. The engines ultimately do their work deterministically, so this is theoretically possible.

If it works, this will amongst other things, enable you classify constructs, which you define as similar, with similar weights, and to possibly ignore others entirely.